# Orbital diagram in which the Aufbau principle is violated

Tags: orbitals, atoms

> The orbital diagram in which the Aufbau principle is violated is:
>   [image]

The answer given for this question is **3**, but according to me if asked for Hund's rule violation then it would be **1**, as electrons are not distributed among the subshell in such a way to give maximum number of unpaired electron with parallel spin.

Comment: Ok. So what is your question?

Comment: That's the ground state for carbon. The pairing energy is lower than the difference between $2s$ and $2p$, so you definitely pair in $2s$ before moving up to $2p$.

Comment: But you’re not being asked for Hund’s rule violation …?

Comment: None of these violate Hund's rule. Aufbau is violated in 3 because $s$ was not filled before moving on to $p$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 3 because according to Aufbau principle electrons are distributed according to energy levels that means S orbital should be filled completely before starting P . This doesn't happen in case 3  ,hence it is the answer.